# How to reverse the effect of this Powershell command?

Tags: ssh, powershell, firewall

I inadvertently executed this command through Powershell:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -Name ssh-client -DisplayName 'OpenSSH Client (Outbound)' -Enabled True -Direction Outbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -RemotePort 22
```

How to reverse the effect of this command back to normal?

Answer (score 1):

The command you've executed makes a new Firewall Rule. To delete that rule, Open Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced security (You can search for it in the search box). Now, go on `Outbound Rules`. Here, look for a rule named as `OpenSSH Client (Outbound)` and delete it.

Alternatively, you can execute `Remove-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "OpenSSH Client (Outbound)"` on your powershell. Please note you will need an elevated PS to execute this command.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell to undo:

```
Remove-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "OpenSSH Client (Outbound)"
```

For more details see
[Remove-NetFirewallRule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/remove-netfirewallrule?view=windowsserver2019-ps).